# Email about sharing is not sent when sharing files using the Google Drive API with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I'm developing a function to upload a file to a specific G-Suite account via the service account, and then share it.

I'm using Google Drive API, and using a service account for authentication.

The service account didn't have any settings(role, permissions, etc...) including 'Domain Wide Delegation'.

The source code is as follows.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info({}, scopes=SCOPES)

file_metadata = {
    "name": "file_to_be_upload.xlsx"
}
media = MediaFileUpload('file_to_upload.xlsx', mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')

drive = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                media_body=media,
                                fields='id').execute()
batch = drive.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)

user_permission = {
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'reader',
    'emailAddress': 'test@gsuite-domain'
}

batch.add(drive.permissions().create(
        fileId=file['id'],
        body=user_permission,
        fields='id'))

batch.execute()
```

As you can see, the source code is an example in the Google Drive API.

When I ran this source code, the e-mail was sending well, but now it is not sending. But file sharing is going well. Only emails are not being sent.

I have never changed any settings. This problem suddenly occurred at some point.

Could please know me this problem's solution?

Thank you.

Comment: `The service account didn't have any settings(role, permissions, etc...) including 'Domain Wide Delegation'.` So you are not using Domain-wide delegation, just the regular service account? Are the files all on the Service account's Drive, or are they on a user's Drive and shared with the service account?

Comment: `This problem suddenly occurred at some point.` Please elaborate; when did this start ocurring?

Comment: Also, have you checked the spam folder of the accounts with which the files are shared?

Comment: I'm sorry for the rate reply, and Thank you for your response.

1. Yes, i'm not using Domain-wide delegation, just the regular service account.

and After uploading a file to Service account's Drive, I shared a user it.

2, 3. I remember that was occurring a warning it contains encrypted a file and service account is outside the organization on shared E-mail, and At one point, E-mail began not to be sent.

Comment: Oh my god... Now is working well! I didn't do anything else, just time passed. What is this issue?

Comment: I don't know of any changes, maybe there was a Gmail send quota limit that was hit so emails weren't going through? Glad that your issue has been resolved though :)